# getting first letters of full name in angular typescript *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new in angular and don't know much about it yet. I am showing a list of people in my angular app. And I want to show first letters of their first name and last name as DP if no picture found for that person. My code looks like below:

```
<div class="people" *ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="s-profile-icon">
        <img src={{user.picture}} alt="Profile" />
    </div>
    <div class="s-name">
        {{user.full_name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Well I know I can use `*ngIf` on `user.picture` to check if picture is empty? But I don't know how to get first letters of name. For example:
 if `user.full_name` contains **Mary Johnson** name and `user.picture` is empty then in place of picture, it should show **MJ** in place of picture. I can design the circle to show letters, just wanted to know how can I get first letters inside loop. Please help me

Comment: You can just do it with `split` and `substring` so for First name you would use array at `0` and `1` for last name. Something like this `"Mary Johnson".match(/\S+/g)[0].substring(0,1);`

Comment: Write a pipe e.g. `iniatials`, transform the value whers you slpit the name on space(s) and resturn concatenated forst letters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a `method` in your component or create custom angular `pipe` for this

create a method to get short name

```
getShortName(fullName) { 
  return fullName.split(' ').map(n => n[0]).join('');
}
```

template

```
<div class="people" *ngFor="let user of users">
    <div class="s-profile-icon">
        <img src={{user.picture}} alt="{{getShortName(user.full_name)}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="s-name">
        {{getShortName(user.full_name)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

the answer above is consider a bad practices because the method will run in every change detection cycle so the best approch is to create a pipe to get the short name

*shortName.pipe.ts*

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "shortName"
})
export class ShortNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(fullName: string): any {
    return fullName
      .split(" ")
      .map(n => n[0])
      .join("");
  }
}
```

*template*

```html
{{'My Name' | shortName}}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shortname)

Comment: Just to be clear; there isn't a pipe in this example

Comment: The way its written it could be construed that a function and an angular pipe are the same thing, hence my caveat :)

Comment: Hey Bro @MuhammedAlbarmawi thanks a lot man! you saved the day! it works just as expected and i'm going to accept your answer :) Cheers

Comment: @Asadullah please do note that a pipe is the more idiomatically correct approach.

Answer (score 4):

The most direct approach would be to write a custom *pipe* for this: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Pipes act as one-way converters, some model value in, some display value out. Once you've written your pipe your template would just be:

```
<div class="s-name">
    {{user.full_name | myCustomNamePipe }}
</div>
```

You could also just bind to a method on the component; but this can be inefficient due to the way change detection works:

```
<div class="s-name">
    {{ getNamePieces(user) }}
</div>
```

Finally, if you just had a user view model and selected into it (using `map`) before display; you could bind directly to a calculated property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help & time. As i'm new in angular and I just tried the simpler solution i.e function approach and it works just as expected. So i will look at your solution too, but for now i'm going to upvote you too ;)

Comment: @Asadullah understood; glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've made some improvements to the solution by @malbarmavi https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621024/3954417

Just added to the pipe a parameter, so you can set a number of chars to show.

*shortName.pipe.ts*

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "shortName"
})
export class ShortNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(fullName: string, numChars: number = 2): any {
    return fullName
    .split(" ").slice(0,numChars)
      .map(n => n[0].toUpperCase())
      .join("");
  }
}
```

*template*

```html
{{'My Name' | shortName:2}}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shortname-u7k8v4?)